# how to fix correlated subquery on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a correlated subquery but I'm not able to figure out what i am doing wrong. Every time I try to run it I get Unknow colunm in 'on clause':

so given this schema

```
create table promotion(PK int, name varchar(255));
create table uiExperienceLevel(PK int, code varchar(255));
create table xp2promo(SourcePk int, TargetPk int);

insert into promotion values(1,'Desktop promotion');
insert into promotion values(2,'Ipad promotion');

insert into uiExperienceLevel values(1,'Desktop');
insert into uiExperienceLevel values(2,'Iphone');
insert into uiExperienceLevel values(3,'Ipad');

insert into xp2Promo values(1,1);
insert into xp2Promo values(2,2);
```

Why does this query not work?

```
SELECT  promo.PK  FROM promotion as promo 
    WHERE ('Desktop' in 
            (SELECT  uiXpLevel.Code  FROM xp2promo xp2promo 
                                     JOIN uiExperienceLevel uiXpLevel 
                                        ON  uiXpLevel.PK  =  xp2promo.TargetPK  
                                          AND  xp2promo.SourcePK  =  promo.PK )
          )
```

every time I run this I get the following error.

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'promo.PK' in 'on clause'
```

---

PS: I know that I could do exactly the same thing using inner joins, what would not only work but have better performance as well

```
SELECT promo.Pk FROM Promotion as Promo
                JOIN xp2promo xp2promo ON  xp2promo.SourcePK  =  promo.PK
                JOIN uiExperienceLevel uiXpLevel ON  uiXpLevel.PK  =  xp2promo.TargetPK 
       WHERE uiXpLevel.Code ='Desktop'
```

however for academic purposes I would like to know how to fix the subquery

---

EDIT: ok I figured out why,

according to mysql official documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/correlated-subqueries.html

[image]

so I just need to invert the logic to give the ids of promotions with desktop from the inner query and compare the pks outside, like this

```
SELECT  promo.PK  FROM promotion as promo 
    WHERE (promo.PK  in 
            (SELECT  xp2promo.SourcePk  FROM xp2promo xp2promo 
                                     JOIN uiExperienceLevel uiXpLevel 
                                        ON  uiXpLevel.PK  =  xp2promo.TargetPK  
                                          WHERE uiXpLevel.Code = 'Desktop' )
          )
```

Anyway I'll keep the question as reference to anyone facing the same problem

Comment: You can't use outer table in subquery. Add table again in subquery.

Comment: ANSI SQL does it the opposite way. (So I removed that tag.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access a table from sub query. Define instead the table once more in the subquery. Like this

```
SELECT  promo.PK  
FROM promotion as promo 
    WHERE ('Desktop' in 
            (SELECT  uiXpLevel.Code  FROM promotion as promoInner
                                     JOIN xp2promo xp2promo 
                                        ON xp2promo.SourcePK  =  promoInner.PK
                                     JOIN uiExperienceLevel uiXpLevel 
                                        ON  uiXpLevel.PK  =  xp2promo.TargetPK )
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

The reference from WHERE works OK, v5.6 and it must work according to docs.

```
SELECT promo.PK  
FROM promotion as promo 
WHERE 'Desktop' in 
            (SELECT  uiXpLevel.Code  
             FROM xp2promo xp2promo 
             JOIN uiExperienceLevel uiXpLevel 
                    ON  uiXpLevel.PK  =  xp2promo.TargetPK  
             WHERE xp2promo.SourcePK  =  promo.PK )
```

The real reason is **Join Processing Changes in MySQL 5.0.12** https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/join.html

> Previously, the ON clause could refer to columns in tables named to
>   its right. Now an ON clause can refer only to its operands.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE t1 (i1 INT);
> CREATE TABLE t2 (i2 INT); 
> CREATE TABLE t3 (i3 INT);
> SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON (i1 = i3) JOIN t3;
> ```
>
> Previously, the SELECT statement was legal. Now the statement fails with an
>   Unknown column 'i3' in 'on clause' error because i3 is a column in t3,
>   which is not an operand of the ON clause.